# How to do code sharing in NestJS through Yarn Workspaces

Tags: typescript, next.js, nestjs, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to do a proof of concept for a simple monorepo application. I decided to just use `Yarn Workspaces` (I think [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org) maybe here is overkill) to set up my package architecture.

I have a `shared` package that I'm using to share code with the frontend and the backend. I successfully achieved to make it works for the frontend (As I'm using [NextJS](https://nextjs.org) in the frontend there was already a NPM library named [next-transpile-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) to get everything running up smoothly) but now, I'm stuck at the backend, and I'm not sure if it's even possible because I couldn't find information on Google.

Here's the error that it's throwing up when I try to start the API:

```
/Users/Alfonso/git/taurus/packages/shared/dist/index.js:1
export var PRODUCT_NAME = "ACME";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Alfonso/git/taurus/packages/api/dist/app.service.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
```

It's exactly the same error (`Unexpected token 'export'`) that I was getting in the `client` package, but as I mentioned, that NPM lib named `next-transpile-module` fixed it.. so it should be something related to transpilation but I have no idea! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a brief look, it's how the shared library gets compiled that's the problem. ESM vs CJS, essentially. ES Modules use the `exports` syntax (front end libraries especially), but Node still uses CommonJS with `module.exports` so it sees `exports` and throws an error

Comment: And what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> And what would be the solution?

To elaborate on a solution for this. When running yarn workspace I am able to transpile a shared typescript library for Next.js because of `next-transpile-module` by simply running `yarn workspace @project/app start`. The same solution doesn't work for my backend `Nest.js` service. Running `yarn workspace @project/service start` will resolve in `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`.

To fix this, you'll need to build the shared library first targeting `commonjs` and configure the service to run the built code instead.

**project/packages/common/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@project/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "yarn build & node ./dist/index"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

**project/packages/common/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**/project/packages/service/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@project/service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nest start",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@project/common": "*",
    ...
  }
}
```

Built the shared libs to `commonjs` and use the built files instead. There may be better ways of doing this since having to build isn't ideal. It's possible that we can do more with `ts-node` and transpile the shared library at runtime somehow.